# A question regarding the structure "question word + to-infinitive"

Tags: infinitives, clauses

A question word can be used before a to-infinitive to express an **indirect question** about what **should** be done. (cited from [here](http://www.grammaring.com/question-word-to-infinitive))

Does this sentence mean that "question word + to-infinitive" can **only** be used as **object of a verb**? Can the structure be used as subject of a verb, subject complement, object of a proposition, appositive? If so, please give me some examples.

Comment: I did a trivial edit for a neater look. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

> **How to answer your question most effectively** is the task I face.

As you see, this sort of construction can act as the subject of a sentence. In fact, such clauses (the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls them *infinitival interrogatives*) can play all the same roles as ordinary nouns and noun phrases:

> SUBJECT: **How to use infinitival interrogatives** is the question you’re asking.
>   APPOSITIVE: This question, **how to use infinitival interrogatives**, is fairly easy to answer.
>   OBJECT COMPLEMENT: I will make my topic **how to use infinitival interrogatives**.
>   SUBJECT COMPLEMENT: This is **how to use infinitival interrogatives**.
>   COMPLEMENT OF ADJECTIVE: The following examples should make it pretty obvious **how to use infinitival interrogatives**.
>   DIRECT OBJECT: Let me show you **how to use infinitival interrogatives**.
>   INDIRECT OBJECT: I am going to give **how to use infinitival interrogatives** a brief treatment.
>   OBJECT OF PREPOSITION: What I’ve said about **how to use infinitival interrogatives** has been pretty predictable.
>   ATTRIBUTIVE: I’ve tried to make my **how to use infinitival interrogatives** post comprehensive.
>   GENITIVE/DETERMINER: **How to use infinitival interrogatives**’ answer is "Just about any way you use a noun".

Comment: +1 for a (moderately! :) successful attempt in the last example. Apparently there's a Playstation game called *How To Survive*, in which context it's actually perfectly reasonable to write [*The meatiest mode on offer though is **How To Survive’s** story-driven campaign.*](http://www.thesixthaxis.com/2014/11/12/exploring-how-to-survives-diabolical-dead-islands-on-playstation-4/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, but I'd regard that as cheating, since *How To Survive* is a proper noun there, like *How to Succeed in Business Without Really Trying*, not a real interrogative. And my last example is actually a mention, not a use. I've rewritten it.

Comment: Now that really *is* a successful final example! There doesn't seem to be anything like it in Google Books, but I could buy into *"**Have you stopped beating your wife's** implicit accusation is that you **did** beat your wife, regardless of whether you **still** do"*. I wouldn't like to say whether it would be "better" if the question mark itself were included before the genitive **'s**.